# MATLAB filter designer giving out filters with huge DC gains

Tags: filter, control-system, digital-filter

hope y'all beings safe out here and doing well.

I am trying to create a single stage biquad (2nd Order) butter worth filter using MATLAB's filter designer tool.

Just to see, I tried plugging back the filter coefficients that MATLAB give out into a discrete transfer function and then converting that discrete transfer function to a continuous transfer function using the "D2C" command using tustin just to see what I would get (Hopefully something close to what I designed).

Behold, I get roughly the same, but with a huge DC gain? I am curious as to where this came from?

Filter Coefficients:
[image]

Filter Designer Parameters:
[image]

Bode Plot of D2C:

[image]

Transfer Function (DISCRETE):

[image]

Transfer Function (CONTINOUS USING TUSTIN from D2C command):

[image]

Comment: 12.3 dB is not a "huge" DC Gain.

Comment: Well, that helped a lot. What I was trying to get at, Butterworth filters for audio applications are suppose to be ~0dB, me seeing 12.3dB you would imagine.

Comment: You forget to include your gain of 0.22... Your SOS section has a gain of 0.22. 1/.022 = 12 dB

Comment: Now we are talking. Can you further explain? I thought the gain of 0.22 was suppose to be multiplied out with just the denominator numbers.

Comment: You should multiply the gain with the numerator coefficients

Comment: Along with the denominator? Or should I multiply both the num. and den by the gain?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your SOS transfer function has a gain of 0.2205. If you don't include this gain in your analysis, you will get a gain of roughly 12 dB.

Comment: Forgot to multiply the numerator by the gain. Thank you buddy!

Comment: You don't need to multiply the denominator by the gain though... It's useless

Comment: You are correct! My bad